# how to make discord py bot send a message when it is invited to a server

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot and I use this script to make the bot send messages to main channel when it gets invited to a server!
However this doesn't send anything to the server! Please Help!

````py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    print("NEW SERVER WAS JOINED!")
    general = find(lambda x: x.name == 'general',  guild.text_channels)
    if general and general.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:  
        await general.send(f"""
████████╗░░░░░░██████╗░░█████╗░████████╗
╚══██╔══╝░░░░░░██╔══██╗██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝
░░░██║░░░█████╗██████╦╝██║░░██║░░░██║░░░
░░░██║░░░╚════╝██╔══██╗██║░░██║░░░██║░░░
░░░██║░░░░░░░░░██████╦╝╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░
░░░╚═╝░░░░░░░░░╚═════╝░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░
```Thanks For Inviting the bot!
Made with <3 by TOG6#6666 with Tons of help from the TOG6 community!```
***Server Invite:*** https://discord.gg/vSxuAbq""")
        await general.send(f"``` Type $help to view all commands!```")
````

Comment: did you try it without `if` ? Did you check what you have in `general` ? Maybe it has something different then you expecte and this makes that `if` is never executed.

Comment: @furas I'm sorry i didnt frame my question right, like how do i make it send that message to the main channel of whatever the server is, the server doesnt need have the channel general

Comment: Can you try to printing the `general` variable?

Comment: You're trying to send the message to the main channel after the bot joins, the channel doesn't have to be named general but it should be the main channel right? If so how is the bot supposed to know what the main channel is?  Unless maybe you could make the bot check every channel for the channel with the most message but this could take a lot of time before the message could be sent and could slow th bot down a alittle which isn't good. Main channels are more likely to be name general or main so maybe you could look for those or do the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I last time made an answer saying that you could use the on_message, but then I came up with something 2,000 times better! Each server has a system channel and using your discord.py bot, you can find the system channel and make it send it's message there!

That's the best method to do it as most server owners leave a main or important channel as their system channel!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to thank everyone for replying to this post! However I came up with a logic!

Since my bot takes admin permissions, it can post on any channel!

Now the thing is, the bot posts the main message whenever someone says T-BOT(case sensitive)

That way, no one is ever gonna say the bot in its entirety at the same time, the bot posts its first message!

For those wondering how to do it, you can use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_delete) discord event to make it search for the bots name!

I hope I helped someone in the future who is making a [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) bot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
        if channel.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
            await channel.send('I will send this message when I join a server')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m better at discord.js, but I’ll give your discord.py problem a stab…

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    try:
        joinchannel = guild.system_channel
        # The system channel is where Discord’s join messages are sent
        await joinchannel.send('Thanks for inviting me to your server!')
    catch:
        # if no system channel is found send to the first channel in guild
        await guild.text_channels[0].send(<message>)
```